# Firebase reference.on() not firing

Tags: firebase, reference, callback, firebase-realtime-database

In working through the Google Maps APIs Transport Tracker tutorial, everything appears to be working as expected with the exception of the .on() callbacks.  None of the callbacks seems to be firing.

The reference link logged to the console, when clicked on, displays the expected Firebase database path and it is updating at regular intervals.  However, the call back below is never fired.

```
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = firebase.database();

  console.log('Adding callback for current-time changes');
  var ref = db.ref('current-time');
  console.log('ref = '+ref);
  ref.on('value', snapshot => {
    console.log('Current-time snapshot');
    displayTimeElement.textContent = snapshot.val().display;
    console.log(snapshot.val().display);
  });
```

The console logs the following.

```
Adding callback for current-time changes
index.js:500 ref = https://transport-tracker-XXXXX.firebaseio.com/current-time
```

The callback is never fired as confirmed by the console message not being logged as well as the HTML page's displayTimeElement value never updating.  I've also tried setting a breakpoint within the callback but it is never reached.

Hence, the only assumption I can make is that the callback is never firing for some unknown reason.

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: I failed to mention that I'm using Chrome to view the page.

Answer (score 6):

After adding a callback for the cancelCallbackOrContext as illustrated below, it logged that my app did not have read permission.

```
  db.ref('current-time').on
    ('value'
    ,snapshot => {
        displayTimeElement.textContent = snapshot.val().display;
        }
    ,error => {console.log(error);}
    );
```

After changing the database authentication rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

everything worked as required.

It would have been nice if the Transport Tracker tutorial had mentioned this...